# Use only a subset of CSV columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and am trying to read the data from a CSV file. I used:

```
d3.csv("my_csv.csv",function(data){
    console.log(data);
},function(error, data){
   console.log(data[0]); 
});;
```

I can see all the components in the console for each row. What I want to achieve is to extract certain components (features) from each row.

Example row when parsed to object:

```
{LONC: "24", LATC: "55", BASE: "abc", LONT: "37.6", TEMP: "0"}, {}, {}, .....
```

I want my objects to only contain a subset of all the above listed columns:

```
{LONC: "24", LATC: "55", BASE: "abc"}, {}, {}, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it by iterating over the array and  retrieving the desired values

```js
d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(data) {
    debugger;
    console.log(data)
    data = data.filter((d, i) => i !== 'columns');
    data = data.map((d) => {
        return {LONC: d.LONC, LATC: d.LATC, BASE: d.BASE}
    });
  console.log(data)
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

**UPDATE**
Creating a basic example for you. Please run the below code and see the output in console. I don't know why its not working there, can you please see if there is an error in console.

```js
const data = [
{LATC:1, LONC:2, BASE:9,x:1,y:5},
{LATC:2, LONC:6, BASE:8,x:12,y:6},
{LATC:3, LONC:7, BASE:7,x:13,y:7},
{LATC:4, LONC:8, BASE:6,x:3,y:8},
{LATC:5, LONC:9, BASE:5,x:4,y:9},
]

console.log(data);

let newData = [];
newData = data.map((d) => {
 return {LATC:d.LATC, LONC:d.LONC, BASE:d.BASE};
})

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am getting empty array if I try to print newData... also the code is getting to `function(error, data){
   console.log(data[0]);`  Any clues to why is happening

Comment: And if you remove the code added by me, is it working fine ?

Comment: `d3.csv("my_csv.csv",function(data){
    console.log(data);
},function(error, data){
   //console.log(data); 
});;`

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the logic is working. Can you please check if there is an error in console. Seems like a spelling mistake from my end, updated my answer

Comment: I already fixed that error when I tried the logic, apparently, there are 2 reasons thatI was able to figure out. 1. It's not an array of dictionaries, but multiple dictionaries. So the data.map function won't work in the particular case. 2. Since it is being called asynchronously, I am not able to use it. Maybe this might help to understand the question better

Comment: i have added a dummy data, isn't it correct structure?
Have you solved you issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208367/discussion-between-dper-and-jasdeep-singh).

Comment: Updated the solution based on our discussion

Comment: Does it resolve your issue?? Or do you need more assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208427/discussion-between-jasdeep-singh-and-dper).

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your call to [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#csv) indicates you are using D3 version **<5** which used the now deprecated [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) module instead of the modern [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) replacement. When called with three arguments the second argument is a *row conversion function* (emphasis mine):

> An optional *row* conversion function may be specified to map and filter row objects to a more-specific representation; see [*dsv*.parse](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse) for details.
>
> ---
>
> If a row conversion function is specified, the specified function is invoked for each row, being passed an object representing the current row (`d`), the index (`i`) starting at zero for the first non-header row, and the array of column names. If the returned value is null or undefined, the row is skipped and will be omitted from the array returned by *dsv*.parse; otherwise, **the returned value defines the corresponding row object**.

Whatever value is returned from that row conversion function is stored in the resulting data array representing the current row. To have only a subset of columns included for each row just use the row conversion function to build objects comprising only the properties of interest:

```
d3.csv("my_csv.csv",function(d) {
  return {
    LONC: d.LONC,
    LATC: d.LATC,
    BASE: d.BASE
  };
}, function(error, data){
   console.log(data[0]); 
});
```